# Adapting content to the width of container

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a react-native-paper Card component:

```
    <Card className='flex pt-2 pl-2' >
        <View className='flex flex-row w-full'>
           <Card.Cover className='h-20 w-20' source={{ uri: imgUrl }} />
           <View className='w-full break-normal'>
               <Text className='text-textColor font-interSBold'>{title}</Text>
               <Text>{author}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </Card>
```

[Screenshot of the resulting cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTiAj.png)

I am using this to render dynamic data, but if title is too long, then it is overflowing the component. How should I handle this?

I have tried using the `flexWrap` property and `flexShrink`, but neither works.

Comment: `w-full` says that your title should be `width: 100%` of the parent element, which in this case is your entire card.  But since you also have an image, you don't really have 100% of the card width available for your title text.  I would just remove the `w-full` and suspect this will get you pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `w-full` from `<View className='w-full break-normal'>`

```
    <Card className='flex pt-2 pl-2' >
        <View className='flex flex-row w-full'>
           <Card.Cover className='h-20 w-20' source={{ uri: imgUrl }} />
           <View className=' break-normal'> <!--  remove w-full here -->
               <Text className='text-textColor font-interSBold'>{title}</Text>
               <Text>{author}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </Card>
```